# How do I find a string in string with regex?

Tags: regex

So, I have a full HTML page as "string". I want to have **everything** between

```
haalt" border=0px/>
```

and

```
</tr>
```

I've tried the following regexes:

```
haalt" border=0px/>(?s)</tr>
and
haalt" border=0px/>(.*?)</tr>
```

But none of them worked. And yes, I am a newb at regexes.

**AutoIt code**

```
    Local $aStrings = StringRegExp($vBron, 'haalt" border=0px/>(?s)</tr>', 3)
```

The 3 in the end means "Return array of global matches."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post some real code, you're probably missing some escaping in the regex, which could depend on the language you're using.

Comment: You need to specify what regular expression package you're using (Java, C, Perl, etc.).

Comment: I have no idea, although here's the helpfile of StringRegExp: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
haalt" border=0px/>(?s)(.*?)</tr>
```

You need to a) tell the regex engine to make the dot match newlines (`(?s)`) and b) tell the regex engine to actually match something (`(.*?)`).